# Calling Stored Procs in Parallel - Worth It?

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library

I found this code in an ASP.NET application the other day.

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => CallStoredProc1());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => CallStoredProc2() );
...
var task8 = Task.Run(() => CallStoredProc8() );
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, ..., task8);
```

These 8 stored procs are all simple queries on the same SQL Server database.

Is the overhead of introducing parallelism "worth" the negligible savings of invoking 8 stored procedure calls in this case?  If not, any suggestions on a good name for this antipattern?

Comment: I would say it really depends on what each stored proc is actually doing.

Comment: This pattern can help improve performance by reducing the amount of time wasted due to latency between the Web server and SQL Server, which will generally be far greater than any overhead of using the Task Parallel Library.

Comment: It could be, SQL server can do parallel processing so its  a potential time saver.

Comment: The easiest way to find out could be to add some timers and run it with and without the tasks.

Comment: As its not thread safe you presumably need to create/close/dispose 8 SqlConnections per request

Comment: Make sure you call them all from the same transaction, or you are likely to deadlock yourself.

Comment: Do you care about the results?  If not use ServiceBroker to kick the proc async and let all the work happen on the SQL server.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, this pattern will improve performance by increasing amount of used threads, which are limited. `async - await` was designed exactly for the cases like OP's - which do even better and release current thread while waiting for results.

Answer (score 0):

No it not worth it.

Separated thread which only executing Sql database procedure - is waste of thread resources.

In your case actually thread created in line `var task1 = Task.Run(() => CallStoredProc1());` will do nothing useful - only waiting for response from database.

Instead use asynchronous methods of `ADO.NET` and make the methods `CallStoredProc1()` and `CallStoredProc2()` asynchronous. Then you can use them in your `ASP.NET` application

```
Task proc1 = CallStoredProc1Async();
Task proc2 = CallStoredProc2Async();

await Task.WhenAll(proc1, proc2);
```

In this way both procedures will be send to the database and while waiting for response current thread will be freed(returned to the threadpool). When tasks will be completed execution continues with another thread from thread pool.

```
public async Task CallStoredProc1()
{
    using(var conn = new Connection("yourConnectionString"))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("Procedure1", conn))
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @UweKeim, I didn't mention anywhere that `Task = Thread`, but in OP's case `var task = Task.Run(...)` it is a new thread.